# Run local spring boot application in windows docker using ubuntu

Tags: spring-boot, docker, ubuntu, dockerfile

I have spring boot application and trying to run in docker with Ubuntu.
I followed many tutorials but its messy for me as a beginner.

Installed docker in windows, pulled Ubuntu image in docker.
Now how to include my local project in docker Ubuntu. Is it necessary to install all software's required for the project in Ubuntu docker or should i load a java image or tomcat image and use them. How to locate dockerfile in ubuntu as its present in my local project folder. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to run your springboot application inside docker?

Comment: yeah. is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below docker file :- (Update <> with actual jar name from your project)

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
COPY <<your jar name>> app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

then run command

```
docker build -t myspringboot-app .
docker run -p 8080:8080 myspringboot-app
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How to locate this dockerfile. I mean should I create in my project locally and use it or in docker ubuntu. how to do it

Comment: create file with name Dockerfile in your springboot project dir, add jar name like target/jarfile name. and then perform build command

Comment: In my target folder i dont find any jar file. and where should i perform build command(in my project terminal?). please reply

Comment: for that you need to do mvn clean install ( in case of maven ) and gradle build ( in case of gradle)

Comment: where should i perform docker build command (in my project terminal?)

Comment: Yes in terminal and you should be in project working dir

Comment: Its working fine thanks... how to add mongodb to this project in docker

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185123/discussion-between-yash-jagdale-and-rognik).